# Embedding Internet Explorer COM Object in a WPF Application

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer

I'm would like to embed Internet Explorer into an WPF Windows Application.
I have been searching for a way and found that i can make an reference to shdocvw.dll and created an instance of the Internet Explorer Class.

I'm able to open web pages, but it is still in an external window and i would like the page in an UIElement (like an Grid)

How do i do this ?

Comment: Please don't add things like " (C#)" to your titles. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for embedding the Internet Explorer COM Object directly or just a control that does that for you?  The [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control will fulfill that simple plop a web browser in a Grid need.  It comes standard in WPF installations and is very easy to use.

```
<WebBrowser Source="http://msdn.com" Width="{INSERT WIDTH}" Height="{INSERT HEIGHT}" />
```

One caveat of this control is that I believe it always renders like IE7. To get it to render to a newer IE (like 11) you want to set the meta tag on the target pages like shown in the following code.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

It can also be set to `IE=11` explicitly. Remember to set the document types There are other ways to trigger a newer IE experience, but this by far is easiest if you control the embedded web pages.

There are also third-party libraries that can give you even more functionality.